# How the initial kmeans points works in to BigQuery ML?

Tags: machine-learning, google-bigquery, k-means

I'm using BigQuery for machine learning, more specifically the k-means method for an unlabeled dataset where I'm trying to find clusters.
I'd like to know if someone has discovered how the BQ ML initiates the centroids.

I already tried looking at the documentation but either there is nothing or I couldn't find it.

```sql
CREATE MODEL `project.dataset.model_name`
    OPTIONS(
        model_type = "kmeans",
        num_clusters = 3,
        distance_type = "euclidean",
        early_stop = TRUE,
        max_iterations = 20,
        standardize_features = TRUE)
    AS
    (SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.sample_date_to_train`  
    )
```

The results differ a little each time I run.
Has someone experience with that subject?

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is still looking for an answer, recently there has been an update on BigQuery ML about this topic. Two new paramaters have been added to the `CREATE MODEL` statement, i.e.:

- `KMEANS_INIT_METHOD`
- `KMEANS_INIT_COL`

Basically you can set your custom *K* observations (belonging to the data table) that will serve as initial centroids for your *K*-means algorithm. You can find the relative documentation at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create). Maybe it's not the most exciting solution to your problem, but it's still something you can work with if you need reproducibility.

Comment: Nice! They update the docs, now it's possible. Thanks, @ric-s

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it probably uses a similar logic to [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/factorization/KMeansClustering#__init__) (BQML might be using TF under the hood as it is).  Random partitioning seems to be the TensorFlow default, so that would be my guess.

Comment: I got your point, I did not know about that possibility to use [TensorFlow model on BQML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/making-predictions-with-imported-tensorflow-models), maybe even you didn't know haha.
But anyway, I don't have the TF model, I was using the "BQ model" as is, maybe the easier way to create a kmeans model on BQML, but I think in this way we don't ahve the option to set our own initial points.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing different results each time you train the model, is due to the random nature of the initial values assigned to the centroids. The K-means algorithm begins by randomly selecting a value(position) for the k number of centroids chosen. If you review this documentation it explains the exact process when using the K-means algorithm[1](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/clustering/algorithm/run-algorithm).